# S-Domain Current Equation for Natural Response of LC Circuit

Tags: current

[image]

**Problem Statement:** In the following circuit, in the initial condition, K is closed and a steady state is reached. At t=0,
the switch is opened. What is the current through the inductor?

**What I Think So Far:**

$$I_L(0) = 5A$$

$$I_C(0) = 0V$$

$$KVL: sLI(s) - LI_o - \frac{I(s)}{sC} = 0$$

$$I(s)=\frac{LI_o}{sL-\frac{1}{sC}}$$

**My Confusion:** I run into problems when I go to do a partial fraction expansion / inverse Laplace transform on s-domain current. Am I setting this up correctly? All the examples I find in the text and online have a resistor included in the circuit, which seems to make the equations a little nicer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: In the time domain the current through the inductor will become a nice cosine wave centered around 0, \$cos(at)=\dfrac{s}{s^2+a^2}\$. If you multiply your \$I(s)\$ by \$\dfrac{s}{s}\$ you'll get something that has the *s* on the right place. Maybe your equation is correct, maybe it's not.

Comment: If you find the problem easier with a series resistor, then add one, and set it to zero once you've derived the Laplace equation.